# How do I know which files to transfer from /user/Library during a by-hand migration onto a new Mac?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, install, migration

My 2019 Mac, running High Sierra, recently crashed. The data has been recovered by the computer store folks onto a hard drive. I just bought a new M1 Mac, which is still in its box and which I assume will be running Monterey.

I told the computer store guy I wanted to do as close to a migration of all the data on the old computer onto the new computer as I could get. He said that I should just set up the new computer and then drag and drop everything from the hard drive he'd given me to the new computer with one exception: rather than transferring the folder /user/Library, I should decide what I want to keep from among its contents and then transfer those to the /user/Library of the new computer.

There are approximately four billion gajillion files in /user/Library on the hard drive, and I have no idea what most of them are, so I have no idea what I want to keep from among its contents. A look at [this article](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/setting-up-a-new-mac-should-you-migrate-or-do-a-clean-installation/) suggests that, to make sure I don't lose anything, the folders I should copy are:

- Application Support
- Containers
- Group Containers
- Calendars
- Fonts
- HomeKit
- Music
- Keychains
- Mail
- Preference Panes
- Safari

If I copy these folders and only these folders from /user/Library on the hard drive of data from the old computer into /user/Library of the new computer, is there anything I'm risking losing?

Note that until recently I was doing my email via POP rather than IMAP, so I can't just get all my email from the server again.

I hope I've been clear here and included all the information necessary to answer the question—if I haven't, please let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: Basically you need everything from ~/Library except Caches and Host specific stuff - plus some apps do add host specific stuff in there which can cause issue. The simlest way is use Apple's Migration Assistant to migrate from a backup. 9This will include stuff from Preferences as well)

Comment: @mmmmmm Alas, according to the guy the data on the hard drive can't be used as a backup to migrate from. Would it be a problem if I just transferred all the contents of the old library into the new library, folder by folder? The guy said that the reason not to just drag and drop the folder was because of hidden files. If I only transfer files I can see, then would that be okay?

Comment: I meant from and existing backup

Comment: However you can copy from the original directories - there should be no relevant hidden files in the root of ~/Library/Application Suppor or Preferences. I have done this but install an app first and then copy over data for that one app if the data makes sense.

Comment: @mmmmmm Thank you! The problem is that the disk with the existing backup is screwed up so I can't actually restore from it.

Is there a chance there are hidden files in other folders in ~/Library? I'd love to just copy the contents of each folder from the data drive into the folder in the new library—so copy the contents of ~/Library/Accessibility, ~/Library/Accounts, ~/Library/Application Scripts, all the way down to ~/Library/WebKit. Or is that a bad idea? Since you say I need "basically everything"....

Forgive me if I'm slow to follow what you're saying. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Basically it works for most cases but for some apps it won't.